# Oracle SQL - variable number of columns in model clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking into the Oracle SQL Model clause. I am trying to write dynamic Oracle SQL which can be adapted to run for a varying number of columns each time, using this model clause. However I am struggling to see how I could adapt this (even using PL/SQL) to a dynamic/generic query or procedure

here is a rough view of the table I am working on

```
OWNER||ACCOUNT_YEAR||ACCOUNT_NAME||PERIOD_1||PERIOD_2||PERIOD_3||PERIOD_4||PERIOD_5||PERIOD_6||....
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 9640||     2018   ||something  1||   34   ||  444   ||   982  ||  55    ||   42   ||  65    ||        
 9640||     2018   ||something  2||   333  ||  65    ||   666  ||  78    ||   44   ||  55    ||
 9640||     2018   ||something  3||   6565 ||  783   ||   32   ||  12    ||   46   ||  667   ||
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
select OWNER, PERIOD_1, PERIOD_2, PERIOD_3, PERIOD_4, PERIOD_5, PERIOD_6, PERIOD_7, PERIOD_8, PERIOD_9, PERIOD_10, PERIOD_11, PERIOD_12, ACCOUNT_YEAR, ACCOUNT_NAME
from DATA-TABLE
where OWNER IN ('9640') and PERIOD_1 is not null 
MODEL  ignore nav 
Return UPDATED ROWS
PARTITION BY (OWNER, ACCOUNT_NAME)
DIMENSION BY (ACCOUNT_YEAR)
MEASURES (PERIOD_1,PERIOD_2, PERIOD_3, PERIOD_4, PERIOD_5, PERIOD_6, PERIOD_7, PERIOD_8, PERIOD_9, PERIOD_10, PERIOD_11, PERIOD_12)
RULES
(
          PERIOD_1[2021] = PERIOD_1[2018] * 1.05,
          PERIOD_2[2021] = PERIOD_2[2018] * 1.05,
          PERIOD_3[2021] = PERIOD_3[2018] * 1.05,
          PERIOD_4[2021] = PERIOD_4[2018] * 1.05,
          PERIOD_5[2021] = PERIOD_6[2018] * 1.05,
          PERIOD_7[2021] = PERIOD_7[2018] * 1.05,
          PERIOD_8[2021] = PERIOD_8[2018] * 1.05,
          PERIOD_9[2021] = PERIOD_9[2018] * 1.05,
          PERIOD_10[2021] = PERIOD_10[2018] * 1.05,
          PERIOD_11[2021] = PERIOD_11[2018] * 1.05,
          PERIOD_12[2021] = PERIOD_12[2018] * 1.05

)
ORDER BY ACCOUNT_YEAR asc;
```

As you can see in the measures and rules section, I am currently hardcoding each period column into this query

I want to be able to use this model clause (well specifically the rule part in a flexible way, so I can have a query which could be run for say, just period 1 -3, or period  5-12...

I have tried looking into this but all examples show the left hand side of the rule (e.g. PERIOD_12[2021] =...) to explicitly refer to a column in a table, rather than a parameter or variable I can swap in for something else simply

Any help on how I might accomplish this through SQL or PLSQL would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should try to avoid dynamic columns by changing the table structure to a simpler format. SQL is *much* simpler if you store the data vertically instead of horizontally - use multiple rows instead of multiple columns.

If you can't change the data structure, you still want to keep the `MODEL` query as simple as possible, because the `MODEL` clause is a real pain to work with. Transform the table from columns to rows using `UNPIVOT`, run a simplified `MODEL` query, and then transform the results back if necessary.

If you really, really need dynamic columns in a pure SQL statement, you'll either need to use an advanced data type like Gary Myers suggested, or use the Method4 solution below.

### Sample Schema

To make the examples fully reproducible, here's the sample data I used, along with the MODEL query (which I had to slightly modify to only reference 6 variables and the new table name).

```
create table data_table
(
    owner number,
    account_year number,
    account_name varchar2(100),
    period_1 number,
    period_2 number,
    period_3 number,
    period_4 number,
    period_5 number,
    period_6 number
);

insert into data_table
select 9640,     2018   ,'something  1',   34   ,  444   ,   982  ,  55    ,   42   ,  65   from dual union all
select 9640,     2018   ,'something  2',   333  ,  65    ,   666  ,  78    ,   44   ,  55   from dual union all
select 9640,     2018   ,'something  3',   6565 ,  783   ,   32   ,  12    ,   46   ,  667  from dual;

commit;
```

MODEL query:

```
select OWNER, PERIOD_1, PERIOD_2, PERIOD_3, PERIOD_4, PERIOD_5, PERIOD_6, ACCOUNT_YEAR, ACCOUNT_NAME
from DATA_TABLE
where OWNER IN ('9640') and PERIOD_1 is not null 
MODEL  ignore nav 
Return UPDATED ROWS
PARTITION BY (OWNER, ACCOUNT_NAME)
DIMENSION BY (ACCOUNT_YEAR)
MEASURES (PERIOD_1,PERIOD_2, PERIOD_3, PERIOD_4, PERIOD_5, PERIOD_6)
RULES
(
          PERIOD_1[2021] = PERIOD_1[2018] * 1.05,
          PERIOD_2[2021] = PERIOD_2[2018] * 1.05,
          PERIOD_3[2021] = PERIOD_3[2018] * 1.05,
          PERIOD_4[2021] = PERIOD_4[2018] * 1.05,
          PERIOD_5[2021] = PERIOD_5[2018] * 1.05,
          PERIOD_6[2021] = PERIOD_6[2018] * 1.05

)
ORDER BY ACCOUNT_YEAR, ACCOUNT_NAME asc;
```

Results:

```
OWNER  PERIOD_1  PERIOD_2  PERIOD_3  PERIOD_4  PERIOD_5  PERIOD_6  ACCOUNT_YEAR  ACCOUNT_NAME
-----  --------  --------  --------  --------  --------  --------  ------------  ------------
9640       35.7     466.2    1031.1     57.75      44.1     68.25          2021  something  1
9640     349.65     68.25     699.3      81.9      46.2     57.75          2021  something  2
9640    6893.25    822.15      33.6      12.6      48.3    700.35          2021  something  3
```

### UNPIVOT approach

This example uses static code to demonstrate the syntax, but this can also be made more dynamic if necessary, perhaps through PL/SQL that creates temporary tables.

```
create table unpivoted_data as
select *
from data_table
unpivot (quantity for period_code in (period_1 as 'P1', period_2 as 'P2', period_3 as 'P3', period_4 as 'P4', period_5 as 'P5', period_6 as 'P6'));
```

With unpivoted data, the `MODEL` clause because simpler. Instead of listing a rule for each period, simply partition by the PERIOD_CODE:

```
select *
from unpivoted_data
where OWNER IN ('9640')
    and (OWNER, ACCOUNT_YEAR, ACCOUNT_NAME) in
    (
        select owner, account_year, account_name
        from unpivoted_data
        where period_code = 'P1'
            and quantity is not null
    )
MODEL  ignore nav 
Return UPDATED ROWS
PARTITION BY (OWNER, ACCOUNT_NAME, PERIOD_CODE)
DIMENSION BY (ACCOUNT_YEAR)
MEASURES (QUANTITY)
RULES
(
    QUANTITY[2021] = QUANTITY[2018] * 1.05
)
ORDER BY ACCOUNT_YEAR, ACCOUNT_NAME, PERIOD_CODE;
```

Results:

```
OWNER  ACCOUNT_YEAR  ACCOUNT_NAME  PERIOD_CODE  QUANTITY
-----  ------------  ------------  -----------  --------
 9640          2018  something  1  P1                 34
 9640          2018  something  1  P2                444
 9640          2018  something  1  P3                982
...
```

### Dynamic SQL in SQL

If you really need to do this all in one query, my open source package [Method4](https://github.com/method5/method4) can help. Once the package is
 installed, you call it by passing in a query that will generate the query you want to run.

This query returns the same results as the previous `MODEL` query, but will automatically adjust based on the columns in the table.

```
select * from table(method4.dynamic_query(
    q'[
        --Generate the MODEL query.
        select
            replace(replace(q'<
                select OWNER, #PERIOD_COLUMN_LIST#, ACCOUNT_YEAR, ACCOUNT_NAME
                from DATA_TABLE
                where OWNER IN ('9640') and PERIOD_1 is not null 
                MODEL  ignore nav 
                Return UPDATED ROWS
                PARTITION BY (OWNER, ACCOUNT_NAME)
                DIMENSION BY (ACCOUNT_YEAR)
                MEASURES (#PERIOD_COLUMN_LIST#)
                RULES
                (
                #RULES#
                )
                ORDER BY ACCOUNT_YEAR, ACCOUNT_NAME asc
            >', '#PERIOD_COLUMN_LIST#', period_column_list)
            , '#RULES#', rules) sql_statement
        from
        (
            --List of columns.
            select
                listagg(column_name, ', ') within group (order by column_id) period_column_list,
                listagg(column_name||'[2021] = '||column_name||'[2018] * 1.05', ','||chr(10)) within group (order by column_id) rules
            from user_tab_columns
            where table_name = 'DATA_TABLE'
                and column_name like 'PERIOD%'
        )
    ]'
));
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't.

You can get an idea of the underlying obstruction if you understand the PARSE, BIND, EXECUTE flow of SQL as demonstrated by the DBMS_SQL package

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html#GUID-BF7B8D70-6A09-4E04-A216-F8952C347BAF

A cursor is opened and an SQL statement is parsed once. After being parsed, a DESCRIBE_COLUMNS can be called which tells you definitively what the columns will be returned by the execution of that SQL statement. From that point you can do multiple BIND and EXECUTE executions, putting different values for variables into the same statement and re-running. Each EXECUTE may be followed up by one of more FETCHes. None of the bind, execute or fetch can affect what columns are returned (either in number of columns, name, order or datatype).

The only way to change the columns returned is to parse a different SQL statement.

Depending on what you want at the end, you might be able to use a complex datatype (such as XML or JSON) to return data with different internal structures from the same statement (or even in different rows returned by the same statement),